# is there any .net or delphi component for showing Catia files?

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, components, catia

is there any .net or delphi component for showing  [Catia](http://www.3ds.com/products/catia) file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no .net or delphi components used to display CATIA files.

CATIA is a proprietary CAD platform with its own ecosystem, and you must be a part of it (as a DS partner) in order to manipulate CATIA data.

Alternatively, if you or your company have sufficient resources, there exist some proprietary C++ libraries witch allows to translate CATIA files into other formats better suited for visualization (such as VRML). From that point, you could make some wrapper around one of these libraries for your specific language, and render VRML directly using some existing libraries.

Comment: where can we find these kinds of libraries please? thanks

Comment: @aaron there is a few companies that are specialized on this: Cortechnologie (disclaimer: I used to work for them), Datakit, and 3DS Spatial

Answer (score 1):

which version of catia? free/shareware/paid components? what do you want to accomplish in Catia? maybe an Catia api can do that for you.

here you have a forum to ask:

http://www.mcadcentral.com/catia/forum/forum_topics.asp?FID=19

I believe there are people which can provide you the best answers.

Best regards,
Radu

Comment: +1 Seems mean to downvote the only person who even attempted to help the OP